# Позиция заднего фона на сайте

Tags: html, css

Имеется [сайт](http://sem-mais.ru).

На заднем плане находится следующее [изображение](http://smages.com/images/ground2.jpg).
В правом нижнем углу находится пара героев составляющих саму суть картины.

Встал вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы их было видно всегда, при любом разрешении экрана?

**Update:**
Проблема была решена следующим способом:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-position: bottom right;
```

Comment: @jFox, я вижу два варианта:

1. Принудительно растянуть изображение (`width:100%; height: 100%`)
2. Вырезать героев и поместить в угол родительского элемента (`position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0` изображению и `position: relative` родительскому элементу). Этот вариант более предпочтителен, но придется повозиться с вырезанием.

Контент на сайте абсолютно волшебный.

Comment: а что если попробовать background-size: cover; background-position: top right; или вариации (p.s. картинка должна задаваться через background-image)

Comment: Какой-то сайт сатанистский) @jFox, если вы сами нашли решение проблемы, то ответьте на свой вопрос самостоятельно и примите ответ как правильный.

Comment: @jFox, сердечно прошу прощения, но вот как это выглядит на 1920 на 1080: http://imgur.com/OQprjRm

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была решена следующим способом:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: bottom right;
```

расширил задний фон изображения по ширине до 2560px